# Hardware requirement vending machine?

Tags: embedded, hardware

I want to create my own vending machine from scratch. But without the money aspect. Just a basic machine where a person has to select a number and than the appropriate item will come out of the machine.

What hardware do I need for this? Can someone point me in the direction to get started with this?

Comment: This sounds like a fine project for an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/)...

Comment: sparkfun.com is a source for a number of items, lots of different kinds of buttons, many different microcontrollers, arduino, msp430 launchpad, mbed, etc, etc.  motors and other mechanicals.

Comment: Isn't "what hardware do I need" explicitly off topic on Stack Overflow?  This is a programming questions and answers site.

Comment: I chose an Atmel UTC3 when I first did this. Nowadays, I would recommend a Raspberry Pi. I wonder if you could do it with a$5 Pi Zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the ones with the little rotating coil that turns one full revolution and drops a packet of goodies or some freshly used panties into a chute?

Well, on a budget, I'd go look up Arduino projects that use 8-segment display drivers and a numeric keypad.  You probably need two 8-segment units - one for the A/B/C etc, the other for the 1/2/3.  Perhaps something related to burglar alarms would be suitable?

You also want some stepper motors and drivers.  You can pull the motors out of old 3.5-inch floppy drives.  Since you only ever need to drive one motor at a time, you may be able to feed the relevant stepper motor wires into a single driver chip and have some logic line-selectors to liven the appropriate wires.

Presumably you can arrange your motors in a grid, and have two selection circuits - one for row and for column.  You might need to use relays instead of logic gates depending on how much current the motors require.  I'm an electronics wannabe with no time to actually embark on these projects so take my advice with a grain of salt...

If you are just doing this privately and don't have an Arduino development board, it might be more cost-effective to build it with the new Raspberry-Pi...  Although that is a full-blown computer and probably overpowered for the task.

For the wire coils, I imagine you can go to an engineering manufacturer and get them to make you some out of stainless...  But since you're on a budget you can just have a go yourself - coil some kind of stiff wire around a large cardboard roll or something.  In New Zealand we use galvanised "number-8" wire for just about anything.  It's not recommended if you require food-grade hygiene though!!

Oh, I suppose you need a coin slot mechanism too...  Have a look at the DIY video arcade game subculture.  You should be able to find something that accepts coins.  Although accepting multiple denominations and giving appropriate change will be a much fancier unit than they are accustomed to.

Comment: Oops, I think I meant 7-segment, not 8-segment! =)

Answer (score 1):

Have a poke around hackaday.com and dangerous prototypes, tonnes of projects using all the principles (user input, mechanisms, actuators, controllers). There's an infinite number of ways to skin this cat depending how the mood takes you and time/budget etc.

Also well worth looking at re-purposing / recycling old hardware, skim eBay and any nearby dumpsters / thrift stores for hardware that can be bent to your purpose - everything from actual old vending machines you could fix up / modify to childrens' toys that could be hacked about to donate mechanisms, buttons, etc. Computer printers and CD/DVD drives are a good source of moving parts and the controlling electronics.

Control wise, arduino is the obvious default choice these days but there are plenty of other options (PIC, MSP430 being two obvious contenders, raspberryPi being overkill but within budget), and if you're hoping to learn some useful stuff then arduino is not as desirable as coding in C on one of the alternatives.